# EmEditorマクロで日付ライブラリを使用できますか？

Tags: javascript, emeditor

EmEditor 20.6.0 professionalを使用しています。
マクロの練習中で、現在日付処理を行おうとしています。

例えば、date = new Date();ではなく、moment.jsやdays.js等を使用することは可能なのでしょうか？
#includeを行ってもうまくいきませんでした。

具体的には、識別子がありません。というエラーが出ております。
ご教示お願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

残念ながら、現在の EmEditor がサポートしている JavaScript は [JScript 5.8](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) で、[ECMAScript 3](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) に相当します。最近のバージョンの JavaScript で新たに追加された言語機能には対応していません。したがって、新しいバージョンの JavaScript の対応が必須となる `moment.js` や `days.js` などのライブラリには対応していません。将来のバージョンで JavaScript のモダン化を検討させてください。ただし、置換表現には、Chakra (ECMAScript 5 相当) が使用されています。